# Flutter text ellipsis deleting last word

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want to use TextOverflow.ellipsis but its deleting last for for make it ellipsis and its looks really ugly. How can i make it without deleting any word ?

[image]

For example when i make with fade and softwrap false its working as i wanted but i want to make it as ellipsis. But when i use ellipsis

[image]

Its being like that and its really looks ugly. How can i fix it ? Thanks for helps!

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue of flutter. See this 4 year old discussion:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18761

There are some possible workarounds mentioned there, but none of them are perfect in my opinion.

I also hope that some day it gets fixed but it doesn't look like they are going to fix it any time soon.

Comment: Thanks for response brother. So I cant do anything for make it like this ? Haven't any 3rd party library or what for it ?

Comment: @UgurcanUcar I have no idea. Maybe there is, but I don't know about it

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. If anyone facing that problem i found a 3rd party library.
https://pub.dev/packages/text_helpers
With InlineText its worked as i wanted.

Example Code :

```
                      InlineText(
                        title,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 109, 66, 239),
                            fontSize: 21,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                      ),
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ellipse` along with `softwrap` false. it will work as you needed.

Check this out::

```
Text(
                  'Sikayet viya Danishments',
                  softWrap: false,
                  maxLines: 1,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 13.0,
                    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                    color: Colors.purple,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: thanks for response. When i tried it it didnt work on me. But of course they can try too. Its worked with fade but with ellipsis it didnt work.