# Is there a way to use overflow.ellipsis to show part of a text with dots using flutter?

Tags: flutter, containers, overflow

[image]  Here is my code:

```
                                       Expanded(
                                                  child: Text(
                                                   "Ambattur Industrial Estate",
                                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                                      fontSize: 15,
                                                      fontWeight:
                                                          FontWeight.bold,
                                                      color: Colors.black,
                                                      // height: 1.5,
                                                    ),
                                                    overflow: TextOverflow
                                                        .ellipsis,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
```

My output is " Ambattur ... " with some space in the right.
But I need this " Ambattur Ind... " .
Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: could you include the ui you want?

Comment: Just increase your expanded widget flex to more than one. You will see more letters

Answer (score 0):

It's a well known issue of flutter. You can read this discussion on https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18761

The comments there have some suggested workarounds, but they are far from ideal in my opinion.

I would suggest to use `TextOverflow.fade` instead. It's maybe uglier but at least cuts of the word at the right spot.

Comment: @Sindu maybe this answer works for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72855694/1514861